# Move listview item left and right by clicking on it

Tags: android, android-listview, swipe

I want to implement moving of listview item to right or left clicking on it
I have use this code for listv [swiplistview](https://github.com/huazhiyuan2008/SwipeListView)
I have a listview like below,

[image]

list item have two view left view (contain one textview ) and right view (contain two button)

Now when I tap on row left view move left side and right view will display, (row move left side) like below

[image]

now if I again click on that row right view will move at right side and textview will display (row moves at right)
What changes I have to done in it ? or add animation in listview item click ??

Comment: Well what are you doing now in OnListItemClick ? You should do the reverse. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: You tell that you are 'clicking'. But don't you mean 'swipe to left or right'?

Comment: no I am not talking about swipe, swipe is working fine, but I want swipe functioanality on clicking

Comment: So if the user clicks, the view should move to the left. And if the user clicks again the view should move back to original position?

Comment: You realise that 'click back' is already functioning now?

Answer (score 0):

In `SwipListView.java` change

```
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            log("============ACTION_UP");
            clearPressedState();
            if (mIsShown) {
                hiddenRight(mPreItemView);
            }
```

to

```
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            showRight(mCurrentItemView); 

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            log("============ACTION_UP");
            clearPressedState();
            if (mIsShown) {
                if ( mPreItemView != null) 
                     hiddenRight(mPreItemView);
            }
```

Comment: I find the answer , I will post it here shortly , thanks for your reply

Comment: Hey Jayesh, please post your answer it will be useful.